Is (p == NULL) the same as (*p == 0) in C++?
My C++ code has the following:
 if (p == NULL || *p == 0)

I wonder if this is redundant?
Is (p == NULL) the same as  (*p == 0)?
Why or why not?

No it's not the same.p == NULL is checking the address stored in the pointer. *p == 0 dereferences the poiinter and checks what it points to.

The expression *p is exactly equal to p[0]. So *p == 0 checks if the first element of p is equal to zero.

No one is checking whether the pointer is null while the other is checking the pointed to value is zero or not. Good c++ book

Also note that order matters. If p is a null pointer, then you can't dereference it (it leads to undefined behavior). And the logical OR operator || uses short-circuit evaluation, which means if p == NULL is true, then *p == 0 will not be evaluated.

On a different note, NULL is a macro that usually expands to 0, and is kept for backward compatibility with C. In C++ you should really be using nullptr.

Do you see the asterisk sign *? If yes, why you think both comparisons are the same.

p tells you where something is; *p tells you what that thing is. You know the difference between where you are and who you are.

p == whatever compares the value of p to whatever.
*p == whatever dereferences p and compares the pointee to whatever.

When p is a null pointer then dereferencing it is undefined.
*p can equal 0 when p points at a memory location where the value 0 is stored.

Are they the same? No.
Why? Because the value of a pointer is not the value of the pointee.

The code assumes that p is either a valid pointer or a null pointer. It checks if it is a null pointer, if not it can continue to dereference it.
Making that assumption is rather common, however it is not safe. There are many invalid pointers that are not null and cannot be dereferenced. The better alternative is to not use raw pointers in the first place.


Is (p == NULL) the same as (*p == 0) in C++?

No, they're not same.
The former p == NULL checks if the pointer p is null or not.
The latter *p==0 checks if the value that is pointed to by the pointer p is zero or not. This is because *p is equivalent to p[0] which gives us the pointed to value.

Note that in modern c++ one should use nullptr instead of NULL

The 2 are not the same.

The expression p == NULL is checking the address stored in the pointer itself. It is true if the address is NULL.

The expression *p == 0 dereferences the pointer and checks what it points to (note that *p is equivalent to p[0]). It is true if the pointer points to a value of 0.


The code you posted is quite typical when you want to check if a pointer points to 0 or any other value. This is because you have to check that the pointer holds a valid (not null) address (unless you are sure it is), before checking what it points to. Dereferecing a null pointer causes UB (Undefined Behvaior).
A side note:
NULL is a legacy from C. Practically speaking is it a macro defined as 0. In C++, it is better to compare a pointer to nullptr.

@RemyLebeau thanks for the typo fixes etc. However "iff" was not a typo - I meant if-and-only-if. But maybe using a regular "if" is less confusing.

If p is a pointer then it can be compared against NULL or nullptr, which typically means that the pointer is initialized but not yet set to point at any data.
*p is dereferencing, meaning accessing the contents of the address pointed at. This can only be done on pointers that point at valid data - dereferencing a null pointer invokes undefined behavior.
Therefore, if we want to check if some data contents accessed through a pointer is 0, but we aren't sure if the pointer points anywhere meaningful, we would have to check if it's a null pointer before accessing it.
The most basic and readable way to do that would be this:
if(p != NULL)
{
  if(*p == 0)
  {
    // do stuff
  }
}

However, this can also be rewritten as a 100% equivalent boolean expression if(p == NULL || *p == 0).
This is because of the so-called "short circuit evaluation" of the && and || operators. Unlike most operators in C++, these two have a well-defined left-to-right order of evaluation, so p==NULL is guaranteed to be evaluated before *p == 0.
Furthermore, it is also guaranteed that if the result of the operator can be concluded after evaluating the left one alone, the right one will not be evaluated. That is in case of 0 && x or 1 || x, we need not care about what the right operand might evaluate too, since no matter the value of the right operand, the result will end up as false or true respectively.
So in case of p == NULL evaluating to true, we need not evaluate *p == 0 to know that the result of || is true. This makes these boolean expressions similar to if statements. We will know for sure that p is not a null pointer when *p == 0 gets executed.
